# Double series and series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let me start with a simpler version of my actual problem. Say I have a partition $\mathbb{N} = \cup_k I_k$ where the $I_k$ are disjoint, and an absolutely convergent series $\sum_n x_n$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$. I want to show the identity $\sum_n x_n = \sum_k \sum_{i\in I_k} x_i$. In this simple situation I can show this using Fubini's theorem, but actually I'm interested in the situation of Banach space valued series that converge unconditionally, so I'd appreciate a more elementary approach that is better suited for generalization.

Comment: Hmm, that only answers your question if you know that every subfamily of a summable family in a Banach space is again summable. Do you know that?

Comment: This is satisfied in my application and otherwise my identity doesn't make sense for the right-hand side wouldn't be defined (at least if it should hold for every such partition, so that every subfamily appears eventually as a subsum on the right-hand side).

Comment: It is generally the case (in every complete Hausdorff abelian group, a subfamily of a summable family is summable, and you can partition the sums arbitrarily). The question is whether you are familiar enough with that fact that the duplicate in fact answers your question, or you need a proof of that.

Comment: No, unfortunately I'm not familiar with these facts. As far I understand your duplicate suggestion, this only shifts my problem to another perspective/theory?

Comment: Yes, but one where the problem is easier to handle. Anyway, I've reopened the question. If nobody has written an answer when I've returned from dinner, I can.

Comment: Dear Daniel, using the definition of summability I found a proof of my own (so, indeed, the change of perspective was helpful :)). I will later write an answer myself but right now I´m also hungry ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115929/discussion-between-sebastian-bechtel-and-daniel-fischer).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Daniel Fischer's hint, I was able to solve the question on my own. I will focus on my specific issue with Banach space valued series, but the scheme is probably always the same.

I recall the definition of summability in a Banach space from "Analysis in Banach spaces" by Hytönen, van Nerven, Veraar and Weis, Definition 4.1.2. They also have a proposition included that shows equivalence to several other definitions, including invariance under reordering, see Proposition 4.1.6 in-there.

**Def**: An indexed family $(x_j)_j$ in a Banach space $X$ is called summable, if there is $x\in X$ such that for all $\varepsilon > 0$ there is a finite set $F_\varepsilon \subseteq J$ such that if $F\subseteq J$ is a finite set containing $F_\varepsilon$, then $\| x - \sum_{j\in F} x_j \| \leq \varepsilon$. Write $\sum_j x_j = x$.

**Proof**: Let $(x_j)_j$ be a summable family in a Banach space. Note that also its subfamilies are summable, see the comment of Daniel Fischer below and Lemma 4.1.4 in the aforementioned book for a proof of the used characterization. Also, let $\varepsilon > 0$. Moreover, let $J^k$ be a partition of $J$ indexed by the natural numbers.

Put $x_k := \sum_{j\in J^k} x_j$, which is well defined by summability over subcollections. Also, there are finite sets $J^k_0 \subseteq J^k$ such that all finite subsets $J_k' \subseteq J^k$ containing $J^k_0$ satisfy $\| x_k - \sum_{j\in J_k'} x_j \| \leq \varepsilon 2^{-k}$. Similarly, with $x:= \sum_j x_j$ there is a finite set $J_0 \subseteq J$ such that any finite set $J' \subseteq J$ containing $J_0$ verifies $\| x - \sum_{j\in J'} x_j \| \leq \varepsilon$.

Define $J_k' := J^k_0 \cup (J_0 \cap J^k)$ and let $N \geq 0$ be such that $J' := \cup_{k=1}^N J_k' \supseteq J_0$, which is possible by finiteness of $J_0$. Note that $\sum_{k=1}^N \sum_{j\in J_k'} x_j = \sum_{j\in J'} x_j$ by finiteness of the sums. Then

$$\| x - \sum_{k=1}^N x_k \| \leq \| x - \sum_{k=1}^N \sum_{j\in J_k'} x_j \| + \sum_{k=1}^N \| x_k - \sum_{j\in J_k'} x_j \| \leq \varepsilon + \varepsilon \sum_{k=1}^N 2^{-k} \leq 3\varepsilon.$$

Note that the bound is independent of $N$. Hence, we can take the limit $N\to \infty$ to conclude.

Comment: Prove and use the criterion that a family $(x_j)_{j \in J}$ in a Banach space is summable if and only if for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there is a finite $F_{\varepsilon} \subseteq J$ such that for every finite $H \subseteq J$ with $H\cap F_{\varepsilon} = \varnothing$ you have $$\Biggl\lVert\, \sum_{j \in H} x_j\Biggr\rVert \leqslant \varepsilon\,.$$ Completeness of the space is of course essential here. With that criterion the summability of subfamilies is immediate (consider $F_{\varepsilon}\cap J^{k}$).